# What to do Quine McCluskey Minterm having zero

Tags: c++, quine

What to do zero minterm in Quine-McCluskey algorithm?
e.g. Sigma (0,1,3) is the input
Then do we have to ignore first zero minterm while finding prime implicants or we don't care about zero.?
i.e. it's not included in output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minterms are numbered starting with Zero.  In other words, if you have two inputs in your truth table then the four minterms are numbered 0,1,2,3.

```
A B | X
----|----
0 0 | 0    m0
0 1 | 1    m1
1 0 | 1    m2
1 1 | 1    m3
```

Comment: I think you're wrong ... The truth table output would be all 1's